# airflow webserver started but UI doesn't show in browser

Tags: python, airflow

I'm trying to use `airflow` .

I want to take a local test of the dags I wrote. I'm on windows so I decided to install ubuntu WLS following this bief tutorial https://coding-stream-of-consciousness.com/2018/11/06/apache-airflow-windows-10-install-ubuntu/.
Everything seems fine.

I started my db with `airflow initdb`.

Then I run `airflow webserver -p 8080` and it seems running. When I go to http://0.0.0.0:8080/ I can't see any user interface. If I try to run again the `airflow webserver` I got

`Error: Already running on PID 6244 (or pid file '/home/marcofumagalli/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid' is stale)`

so i suppose that webserver is running.

Is it something related to proxy?

Comment: Try http://localhost:8080

Comment: What does `curl http://0.0.0.0:8080/`  return?

Comment: localhost:8080 already did. It keep loading the page without showing anything. Same thing for curl, it's pending without returning anything

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Error: Already running on PID 6244 (or pid file '/home/marcofumagalli/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid' is stale)`

This means that the port 8080 is busy.

Try running the commands below:-

1. `sudo lsof -i tcp:8080`:- will show are the processes running as

`COMMAND   PID       USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
 Python    945 amanraheja    6u  IPv4 0xb7fcab59337d7455      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
 Python   1009 amanraheja    6u  IPv4 0xb7fcab59337d7455      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
 Python   1052 amanraheja    6u  IPv4 0xb7fcab59337d7455      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
 Python   1076 amanraheja    6u  IPv4 0xb7fcab59337d7455      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)
 Python  96034 amanraheja    6u  IPv4 0xb7fcab59337d7455      0t0  TCP *:http-alt (LISTEN)`

2. Kill the PID's by `kill -9 945` and so on..
3. delete the `airflow-webserver.pid` file and start the server again and you will see that it is running fine.

Comment: Also you could kill them all at once with `sudo lsof -i tcp:8080 | grep 'username' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9` , then delete the .pid file.

Comment: @NicoE Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 9):

## mac docker memory issue

I hit this error while developing in my mac, and looking at the logs I found an `exited with code: 137`, which is an [OOM code](https://betterprogramming.pub/understanding-docker-container-exit-codes-5ee79a1d58f6) (although perhaps [not always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59296801/docker-compose-exit-code-is-137-when-there-is-no-oom-exception)).

In any case, I fixed it by increasing the memory limit to 3GB in docker, following [these docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/):
[image]

Comment: I needed to free 4GB of memory and it worked for me.
life saver, thanks

Answer (score 2):

By running `kill -9 PID` resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

hey actually same thing happened with me.
i am sharing following steps which i did.
kill the running **pid** by using **kill pid** command.
then confirm that you have initiated db with ***airflow db init*** command.
and created user by using **airflow users create** command.
after doing this step by step.
use **localhost:8080** in place **0.0.0.0:8080**.
it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

### Note for macOS users who runs Airflow via k8s:

In order to be able to see UI up and running on your browser at `http://localhost:8080/`, you need also to run port forwarding: `kubectl port-forward POD_ID 8080:8080`

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Airflow in a Docker, then killing the PID won't help, neither restarting the service. What you need to do is to search for the Docker container of Airflow's webserver and remove it like this:

```
docker ps
```

> CONTAINER ID     IMAGE   ...                PORTS      NAMES
>
> 25d9df23d557    apache/airflow:2.3.2  ...   8080/tcp   airflow-webserver

```
docker container rm {airflow-webserver}
```