# Docker-compose up with conda not working properly

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, conda

Good afternoon. First of all, I'm very beginner in Docker and I have a ongoing project with Django+PostgreSQL.

I have issue with running docker-compose up. First of all I was facing a error code 137.
I went through the steps. I give docker more ram (was 2GB, I give it 4GB firstly and then expand to 8GB).
[Here is SO thread for this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59296801/docker-compose-exit-code-is-137-when-there-is-no-oom-exception)

Error was solved, but now I'm facing infinity loading on this steps.

' => [3/5] RUN conda install -y --file /conda_files/requirements.txt -c conda-forge -c anaconda   '

It can be going for 2000secs+

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM conda/miniconda3
COPY requirements.txt /conda_files/requirements.txt
RUN conda install -y --file /conda_files/requirements.txt -c conda-
forge -c anaconda
RUN pip install requests-html==0.10.0
COPY . /app/ref_wallet
ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/app/ref_wallet"
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /app/current/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
    volumes:
      - .:/app/current/
    ports:
      - 8082:80
```

The most strange thing. That my colleague can run this code on his Windows PC. And I'm on my MacBook can not.

Any ideas of why it's happening and how I can solve it? Cause currently I don't receive any errors. It's just infinity loading for me now.

Answer (score -1):

Usually if there is infinite loading the issues has to do with the available resources docker may consume. You can change your resources using docker desktop. Personally I always make sure I give Docker all resources it need.

[image]

Comment: I will give a try. I was already expanding memory to 8GB. Maybe I need to add additional CPUs

Comment: Did it fix the problem?