# Troubleshoot docker Exit on 137 when "OOMKilled": false

Tags: python, linux, docker, docker-compose, vcenter

##### What I did

1. Started services on an AlmaLinux server with `docker-compose up`
2. Noticed output of `docker-compose logs` wasn't changing for a while
3. Check `docker-compose ps`

```
$ docker-compose ps
              Name                            Command                State     Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mysupercoolsystem_api_1           python -m mysupercoolsyste ...   Exit 137
mysupercoolsystem_dev_1           sh -c jupyter lab --ip=0.0 ...   Exit 137
mysupercoolsystem_loader_1        /bin/sh -c python -m mysup ...   Exit 137
mysupercoolsystem_predictor_1     /bin/sh -c python -m mysup ...   Exit 137
mysupercoolsystem_trainer_1       /bin/sh -c python -m mysup ...   Exit 137


$ docker ps -a  # just to confirm
72708f3450   hub.nic.dk/nicecompany/mysupercoolsystem   "/bin/sh -c 'python …"   2 days ago    Exited (137) 2 days ago              mysupercoolsystem_trainer_1
3e286cabb0   jupyter/scipy-notebook:33add21fab64        "sh -c 'jupyter lab …"   2 days ago    Exited (137) 2 days ago              mysupercoolsystem_dev_1
246b87f0ac   hub.nic.dk/nicecompany/mysupercoolsystem   "/bin/sh -c 'python …"   2 days ago    Exited (137) 2 days ago              mysupercoolsystem_predictor_1
7d3297092c   hub.nic.dk/nicecompany/mysupercoolsystem   "python -m mysuperc …"   2 days ago    Exited (137) 2 days ago              mysupercoolsystem_api_1
2a07851f9c   hub.nic.dk/nicecompany/mysupercoolsystem   "/bin/sh -c 'python …"   2 days ago    Exited (137) 2 days ago              mysupercoolsystem_loader_1
```

4. Research whether containers were stopped because of out-of-memory

   - Checked virtual host: The docker containers run on a single virtual (vcenter-managed) host. The host is allocated 20GB of RAM and vcenter monitor shows RAM usage peaks at ca. 8GB and not more.
   - **Follow-up:** Talked to sysadmin: Servers were not restarted or explicitly asked to terminate any processes.
   - `docker info | grep Memory` returns `Total Memory: 19.37GiB`
   - checked each container with `docker inspect <container_id>` gives the same `"State"`, apart from the field `"FinishedAt"` which varies with `±0.05` seconds.

```
"State": {
  "Status": "exited",
  "Running": false,
  "Paused": false,
  "Restarting": false,
  "OOMKilled": false,
  "Dead": false,
  "Pid": 0,
  "ExitCode": 137,
  "Error": "",
  "StartedAt": "2021-11-13T10:33:04.785566471Z",
  "FinishedAt": "2021-11-13T10:33:57.1xxxxZ"
```

5. Re-examined my `docker-compose.yml`.

```
$ cat docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  dev:
    image: jupyter/scipy-notebook:33add21fab64
    environment:
      - COMPONENT=develop
    volumes:
      - /opt/mysupercoolsystem:/home/jovyan/work
      - /media:/media
    ports:
      - "3333:3333"
    entrypoint: sh -c "jupyter lab --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=3333 --no-browser --allow-root"

  loader:
    image: hub.nic.com/nicecompany/mysupercoolsystem
    working_dir: "/app"
    volumes:
      - /media:/media

  trainer:
    image: hub.nic.dk/nicecompany/mysupercoolsystem
    environment:
      - COMPONENT=train
    working_dir: "/app"
    volumes:
      - models:/models

  predictor:
    image: hub.nic.dk/nicecompany/mysupercoolsystem
    environment:
      - COMPONENT=pred
    working_dir: "/app"
    volumes:
      - models:/models

  api:
    image: hub.nic.dk/nicecompany/mysupercoolsystem
    environment:
      - COMPONENT=api
    working_dir: "/app"
    ports:
      - "69:69"
    entrypoint: python -m mysupercoolsystem.web_api

volumes:
  models:
```

6. Examine `Dockerfile`. Note: Services that do not have an explicit entrypoint in `docker-compose.yml` inherit the entrypoint from the `Dockerfile`.

```
$ cat mysupercoolsystem/Dockerfile
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
RUN pip install .
ENTRYPOINT python -m mysupercoolsystem
```

7. Checked [similair issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59296801/docker-compose-exit-code-is-137-when-there-is-no-oom-exceptionw) (this issue had `--abort-on-container-exit`-flag as the culprit. I am not using any flags).

#### How to proceed

- Why are the services exiting?
- What can I do to troubleshoot the error?
- Are there other logs I should be checking?
- If I add `restart: unless-stopped` on each service, is there any way to examine docker service exits apart from my own logging via `docker logs`?

Comment: What else is there in the `State` object in the inspect result? No "Error"?

Comment: @AKX I've added the state output. No error.

Comment: Hi @DannyDannyDanny . Any updates on what caused this? I'm facing exactly the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: In my case I reduced the RAM consumption by batch processing the data my program processes. There was no concrete troubleshooting I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

I had a `&& sleep 1h` at the end of my shell script for signaling that it's done (running on this node) and a `health-cmd` of `pidof sleep` configured. Looks like something changed in the Alpine container I'm using which lead to `sleep` not running as an extra process and in the end dockers *health check killed the shell* in the container. Also leading to a 137 (SIGKILL) exit code but not triggerd by the OOM Killer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://pythonspeed.com/fil/ to debug out-of-memory errors in Python (see https://pythonspeed.com/articles/crash-out-of-memory/).

Comment: The docker containers run on a single virtual (vcenter-managed) host. The host is allocated 20GB of RAM and vcenter monitoring shows RAM usage peaks at 8GB and never more. The logs also suggest that OOM is not the problem: `"OOMKilled": false`. Also the program is not supposed to exit - rather it runs in a while-true-do-sleep loop.

Comment: It's jsut that exit code 137 is kill -9, I believe, and something that often does this is Linux out-of-memory killer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
healthcheck:
  disable: true
```

Thanks to @thomas, I discovered that my `python` container was based on `alpine`, which recently suffers from a failing `pidof sleep` healthcheck. This led to the docker daemon killing the container with a 137 exit code but `OOMKilled: false`.

Those using `docker run` directly can add `--no-healthcheck`.

Comment: My solution was writing `/usr/bin/sleep` instead of just `sleep` so the shell would be forced to run the external sleep program and not use a shell builtin for it.