# Why does this ML model keep throwing docker error 137?

Tags: docker, machine-learning

I posted a [similar issue](https://github.com/ServiceNow/picard/issues/110) to the model's Github repo and saw no response, so I've decided to repost it here.

Whenever I attempt to train or evaluate the docker image model, I get error 137. [image: error 137]

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67900629/13046931), I gleamed that Docker was running out of RAM/memory. Since I'm using WSL2, I created a config file (.wslconfig) at %username%. I set the following parameters:

```
#I have 16GB of RAM/memory
memory=15GB 
#i have 6 cores and 12 logical processors
processors=10
# Sets amount of swap storage space
swap=15GB
```

The same problem still happens, so I removed all docker images, and re-pulled them. Still same problem, so I went into Docker Engine and attempted to increase its "defaultKeepStorage". I was forced to reset Docker Desktop when it wouldn't open. Pruning has also been attempted.

Dockerfile:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE

# ------------------------
# Target: dev
# ------------------------
FROM $BASE_IMAGE as dev

ARG TOOLKIT_USER_ID=13011
ARG TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID=13011

RUN apt-get update \
    # Required to save git hashes
    && apt-get install -y -q git curl unzip make gettext \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app
ENV XDG_DATA_HOME=/app/.local/share \
    XDG_CACHE_HOME=/app/.cache \
    XDG_BIN_HOME=/app/.local/bin \
    XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/app/.config
RUN mkdir -p $XDG_DATA_HOME \
    && mkdir -p $XDG_CACHE_HOME \
    && mkdir -p $XDG_BIN_HOME \
    && mkdir -p $XDG_CONFIG_HOME \
    && chown -R $TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID /app

# Install C++ toolchain, Facebook thrift, and dependencies
RUN curl https://apt.llvm.org/llvm-snapshot.gpg.key | apt-key add - \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends software-properties-common \
    && apt-add-repository "deb http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic-9 main" \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        binfmt-support libllvm9 llvm-9 llvm-9-dev llvm-9-runtime llvm-9-tools python-chardet python-pygments python-yaml \
        g++ \
        cmake \
        libboost-all-dev \
        libevent-dev \
        libdouble-conversion-dev \
        libgoogle-glog-dev \
        libgflags-dev \
        libiberty-dev \
        liblz4-dev \
        liblzma-dev \
        libsnappy-dev \
        make \
        zlib1g-dev \
        binutils-dev \
        libjemalloc-dev \
        libssl-dev \
        pkg-config \
        libunwind-dev \
        libmysqlclient-dev \
        bison \
        flex \
        libsodium-dev \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID third_party/zstd /app/third_party/zstd/
RUN cd /app/third_party/zstd \
    && make -j4 \
    && make install \
    && make clean
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID third_party/fmt /app/third_party/fmt/
RUN cd /app/third_party/fmt/ \
    && mkdir _build \
    && cd _build \
    && cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=off -DBUILD_TESTS=off ../. \
    && make -j4 \
    && make install \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -rf _build
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID third_party/folly /app/third_party/folly/
RUN pip install cython \
    && cd /app/third_party/folly \
    && mkdir _build \
    && cd _build \
    && cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DPYTHON_EXTENSIONS=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=off -DBUILD_TESTS=off ../. \
    && make -j4 \
    && make install \
    && cp folly/cybld/dist/folly-0.0.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl /app/ \
    && chown $TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID /app/folly-0.0.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl \
    && pip install /app/folly-0.0.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -rf _build
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID third_party/rsocket-cpp /app/third_party/rsocket-cpp/
RUN cd /app/third_party/rsocket-cpp \
    && mkdir _build \
    && cd _build \
    && cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=off -DBUILD_TESTS=off ../. \
    && make -j4 \
    && make install \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -rf _build
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID third_party/fizz /app/third_party/fizz/
RUN cd /app/third_party/fizz \
    && mkdir _build \
    && cd _build \
    && cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=off -DBUILD_TESTS=off ../fizz \
    && make -j4 \
    && make install \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -rf _build
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID third_party/wangle /app/third_party/wangle/
RUN cd /app/third_party/wangle \
    && mkdir _build \
    && cd _build \
    && cmake -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=off -DBUILD_TESTS=off ../wangle \
    && make -j4 \
    && make install \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -rf _build
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID third_party/fbthrift /app/third_party/fbthrift/
RUN cd /app/third_party/fbthrift \
    && mkdir _build \
    && cd _build \
    && cmake \
        -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
        -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=$(python -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_inc; print(get_python_inc())") \
        -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=$(python -c "import distutils.sysconfig as sysconfig; import os; print(os.path.join(sysconfig.get_config_var('LIBDIR'), sysconfig.get_config_var('LDLIBRARY')))") \
        -Dthriftpy3=ON \
        ../. \
    && make -j4 \
    && DESTDIR=/ make install \
    && cp thrift/lib/py3/cybld/dist/thrift-0.0.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl /app/ \
    && chown $TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID /app/thrift-0.0.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl \
    && pip install /app/thrift-0.0.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -rf _build

# Install Rust toolchain
ENV RUSTUP_HOME=/app/.local/rustup \
    CARGO_HOME=/app/.local/cargo \
    PATH=/app/.local/cargo/bin:$PATH
RUN set -eux; \
    apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        ca-certificates \
        gcc \
        libc6-dev \
        wget \
        ; \
    \
    url="https://static.rust-lang.org/rustup/dist/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/rustup-init"; \
    wget "$url"; \
    chmod +x rustup-init; \
    ./rustup-init -y --no-modify-path --default-toolchain nightly-2021-06-01; \
    rm rustup-init; \
    chmod -R a+w $RUSTUP_HOME $CARGO_HOME; \
    rustup --version; \
    cargo --version; \
    rustc --version; \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*; \
    chown -R $TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID /app/.local/cargo; \
    chown -R $TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID /app/.local/rustup;

# Install Haskell toolchain
ENV BOOTSTRAP_HASKELL_NONINTERACTIVE=yes \
    BOOTSTRAP_HASKELL_NO_UPGRADE=yes \
    GHCUP_USE_XDG_DIRS=yes \
    GHCUP_INSTALL_BASE_PREFIX=/app \
    CABAL_DIR=/app/.cabal \
    PATH=/app/.cabal/bin:/app/.local/bin:$PATH
RUN buildDeps=" \
        curl \
        "; \
    deps=" \
        libtinfo-dev \
        libgmp3-dev \
        "; \
    apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends $buildDeps $deps \
    && curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://get-ghcup.haskell.org | sh \
    && ghcup install ghc \
    && ghcup install cabal \
    && cabal update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends git \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && git clone https://github.com/haskell/cabal.git \
    && cd cabal \
    && git checkout f5f8d933db229d30e6fc558f5335f0a4e85d7d44 \
    && sed -i 's/3.5.0.0/3.6.0.0/' */*.cabal \
    && cabal install cabal-install/ \
        --allow-newer=Cabal-QuickCheck:Cabal \
        --allow-newer=Cabal-described:Cabal \
        --allow-newer=Cabal-tree-diff:Cabal \
        --allow-newer=cabal-install:Cabal \
        --allow-newer=cabal-install-solver:Cabal \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -rf cabal/ \
    && rm -rf /app/.cabal/packages/* \
    && rm -rf /app/.cabal/logs/* \
    && rm -rf /app/.cache/ghcup \
    && chown -R $TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID /app/.cabal \
    && chown -R $TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID /app/.local/bin \
    && chown -R $TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID /app/.local/share/ghcup

# Build Facebook hsthrift
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID third_party/hsthrift /app/third_party/hsthrift/
RUN cd /app/third_party/hsthrift \
    && make thrift-cpp \
    && cabal update \
    && cabal build exe:thrift-compiler \
    && make thrift-hs \
    && cabal install exe:thrift-compiler \
    && cabal clean \
    && rm -rf /app/.cabal/packages/* \
    && rm -rf /app/.cabal/logs/* \
    && chown -h $TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID /app/.cabal/bin/thrift-compiler \
    && find /app/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.*/ -maxdepth 2 -type d -group root -exec chown -R $TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID {} \; \
    && find . -group root -exec chown $TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID {} \;

# Install misc utilities and add toolkit user
ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y \
        zsh fish gnupg lsb-release \
        ca-certificates supervisor openssh-server bash ssh tmux jq \
        curl wget vim procps htop locales nano man net-tools iputils-ping \
        openssl libicu[0-9][0-9] libkrb5-3 zlib1g gnome-keyring libsecret-1-0 desktop-file-utils x11-utils && \
    curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg && \
    echo \
        "deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
        $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io && \
    sed -i "s/# en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/" /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen && \
    useradd -m -u $TOOLKIT_USER_ID -s /bin/bash --non-unique toolkit && \
    passwd -d toolkit && \
    useradd -m -u $TOOLKIT_USER_ID -s /bin/bash --non-unique console && \
    passwd -d console && \
    useradd -m -u $TOOLKIT_USER_ID -s /bin/bash --non-unique _toolchain && \
    passwd -d _toolchain && \
    useradd -m -u $TOOLKIT_USER_ID -s /bin/bash --non-unique coder && \
    passwd -d coder && \
    chown -R $TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID /run /etc/shadow /etc/profile && \
    apt autoremove --purge && apt-get clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* && \
    echo ssh >> /etc/securetty && \
    rm -f /etc/legal /etc/motd

# Build Huggingface tokenizers Rust libraries
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID third_party/tokenizers /app/third_party/tokenizers/
RUN cd /app/third_party/tokenizers \
    && rustup --version \
    && cargo --version \
    && rustc --version \
    && cargo build --release \
    && cp target/release/libtokenizers_haskell.so /usr/lib/ \
    && rm -rf target \
    && find /app/.local/cargo -group root -exec chown $TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID {} \;
ENV TOKENIZERS_PARALLELISM=false

# Install Python toolchain
ENV PYTHONPATH=/app
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir pre-commit "poetry==1.1.7"
# Disable virtualenv creation to install our dependencies system-wide.
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false
# Config file is not readable by other users by default, which prevents
# it from being read on Drone, therefore make it readable.
RUN chmod go+r $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/pypoetry/config.toml
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID pyproject.toml poetry.lock /app/
RUN poetry install --extras "deepspeed" \
    && pip install /app/folly-0.0.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl \
    && pip install /app/thrift-0.0.1-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl \
    && rm -rf $XDG_CACHE_HOME/pip \
    && rm -rf $XDG_CACHE_HOME/pypoetry \
    && chown -R $TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/pypoetry

# Unfortunately, nltk doesn't look in XDG_DATA_HOME, so therefore /usr/local/share
RUN python -m nltk.downloader -d /usr/local/share/nltk_data punkt stopwords

# ------------------------
# Target: train
# ------------------------
FROM dev as train

ARG TOOLKIT_USER_ID=13011
ARG TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID=13011

# Misc environment variables
ENV HF_HOME=/transformers_cache

# Copy Seq-to-seq code
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID ./seq2seq /app/seq2seq/
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID ./tests /app/tests/
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID ./third_party/spider /app/third_party/spider/
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID ./third_party/test_suite /app/third_party/test_suite/
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID ./configs /app/configs/

# ------------------------
# Target: eval
# ------------------------
FROM dev as eval

ARG TOOLKIT_USER_ID=13011
ARG TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID=13011

# Add thrift file
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID picard.thrift /app/

# Build Cython code
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID gen-cpp2 /app/gen-cpp2/
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID gen-py3 /app/gen-py3/
RUN thrift1 --gen mstch_cpp2 picard.thrift \
    && thrift1 --gen mstch_py3 picard.thrift \
    && cd gen-py3 && python setup.py build_ext --inplace \
    && chown -R $TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID /app/gen-py3 /app/gen-cpp2
ENV PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/app/gen-py3 \
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/app/gen-py3/picard

# Build and install Picard
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID cabal.project fb-util-cabal.patch /app/
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID gen-hs /app/gen-hs/
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID picard /app/picard/
RUN cabal update \
    && cd third_party/hsthrift \
    && make THRIFT_COMPILE=thrift-compiler thrift-cpp thrift-hs \
    && cd ../.. \
    && thrift-compiler --hs --use-hash-map --use-hash-set --gen-prefix gen-hs -o . picard.thrift \
    && patch -p 1 -d third_party/hsthrift < ./fb-util-cabal.patch \
    && cabal install --overwrite-policy=always --install-method=copy exe:picard \
    && chown $TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID /app/.cabal/bin/picard \
    && cabal clean \
    && rm -rf /app/third_party/hsthrift/compiler/tests \
    && rm -rf /app/.cabal/packages/* \
    && rm -rf /app/.cabal/logs/* \
    && chown -R $TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID /app/picard/ \
    && chown -R $TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID /app/gen-hs/ \
    && find /app/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.*/ -maxdepth 2 -type d -group root -exec chown -R $TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID {} \; \
    && find /app/.cabal/store/ghc-8.10.*/ -maxdepth 2 -type f -group root -exec chown $TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID {} \;

# Misc environment variables
ENV HF_HOME=/transformers_cache

# Copy Seq-to-seq code
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID ./seq2seq /app/seq2seq/
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID ./tests /app/tests/
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID ./third_party/spider /app/third_party/spider/
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID ./third_party/test_suite /app/third_party/test_suite/
COPY --chown=$TOOLKIT_USER_ID:$TOOLKIT_GROUP_ID ./configs /app/configs/

# Test Picard
RUN python /app/tests/test_picard_client.py \
    && rm -rf /app/seq2seq/__pycache__ \
    && rm -rf /app/gen-py3/picard/__pycache__
```

Comment: I ran into something similar and had to run `docker system prune` and `docker builder prune --all` to clear all prior build cache.  It didn't end up being memory per say but a bloated build cache.  I now run both commands often to keep it cleared out.

Comment: Can you add your Dockerfile and if using a docker-compose file add that as well?

Answer (score 0):

When building images, Docker will use a build cache which serves to reduce duplicate downloads and speed up the overall build.

Over time with repeated builds or build attempts this can become bloated - especially if errors are encountered during the build.  Deleting images often doesn't help as the build cache remains and can run into the tens of  GB's

The running out of memory error isn't very explanatory.

I was able to fix my memory error by deleting all unused images, networks and volumes along with the build cache using `docker system prune` and `docker builder prune --all`

Comment: When running these commands, they didn't free up any additional space. I'd already deleted the previous images and containers using docker desktop. I'm currently repulling the image and I'll remove this comment if it works.